# UICollectionview cellForItemAtIndexPath not getting called when collectionview reload in performBatchUpdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have to animate UICollectionview reloadData, so I have called reloadData in UICollectionView performBatchUpdates.

This animation working perfectly but unfortunately UICollectionviewcell subviews(my custom view) not updated as far as hour debugging noticed that  cellForItemAtIndexPath not called why?

`[UICollectionview performBatchUpdates:^{
            [UICollectionview reloadData];
} completion:nil];`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You don't need to call reloadData in performBatchUpdates. performBatchUpdates is used to group animations related to insert, delete, reload, or move cells or use it to change the layout parameters associated with one or more cells. But your code indicates that you are only doing one of those things so you can just say [UICollectionview reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you show us more code about how you set your subviews?

I guess this may help you: try to set your subviews in  `layoutSubviews`,

Comment: @Maddy It'll be appreciate if you can accept my answer.